# How to process this kind of edge cases in shell script?

Tags: shell

I have a program in Linux to write log into files on a regular interval (for
example: 10 minutes every file), so I have a directory hierachy like this:

> [image: dir hierarchy]

In which, `20151001` stands for the log dir for the day
`2015(year)/10(month)/01(day)`, and `00` stands for the first hour in the day,
and `00.00` stands for the log file for the first 10 minutes in the first hour
of the day.

In my shell script I need to detect if there is any previous log file is empty,
for example if now the time is `2015/10/09 09:32`, the newest log file should be
`20151009/09/09.03`, the file `09.03` could be an empty file, but the other
older files should not be empty. In order to simplify the problem, I just detect
if the previous file is empty, so I just detect if the file `20151009/09/09.02`
is empty. However I have to handle some edge cases, like:

1. If now the time is:

   ```
   2015/10/09 09:01
   ```

   the previous file is in another directory, it’s:

   ```
   20151009/08/08.05
   ```
2. If now the time is:

   ```
   2015/10/09 00:01
   ```

   the previous file is:

   ```
   20151008/23/23.05
   ```

Is there any powerful algorithm or tools to handle my problem, especially the
edge cases?

Comment: Why do you want to do it in a shell script? One language for any problem: this one is trivial with `perl` or `python`... :-)

Comment: What are you going to do if you find an empty file?

Comment: Thanks to your convenient file names, `find dir | sort` will give you the list in chronological order.

Comment: If the script found the previous log file is empty. it will report a warning to related developers by sending email etc.